# The package name is not generated properly after I have created the project in eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse

When I create a spring project in Eclipse, I specify the top-level package name

`com.myapp.controller`

but, it instead creates the package

`com.controller.controller`

I am Korean so I'm sorry I didn't explain it very well.
Thank you for helping me out. Even though we don't know each other, 
Thank you for reading. If you know about this problem, help me ^^

Answer (score 0):

You probably went ahead and created a Class without giving it a package name. This takes some doing, since the New Class Wizard actually populates the "package" field with the name of the project under the assumption that that's probably what you wanted to begin with.

So you have several options here:

1. Create a new class with a proper package name. Eclipse will then create the package structure for you and you won't have to lift a finger worrying about packages.
2. Create the package you want, perhaps even with a package-info.java file in it. Then create a class inside it.
3. Continue using the default package and live with the shame. (Just kidding. That's not a very good option. But if you're just fiddling around it won't hurt too much.)

The reason Eclipse doesn't just ask you what to name "the package" is that there could well be more than one. It's quite common for a project to have several packages in it. So instead, Eclipse makes creating packages easy.

Detailed Information: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/983472/